# How to read a JSON static file in web2py

Tags: python, json, web2py

I'm putting together my first web2py app, and I've run into a bit of a problem. I have some data stored in `static/mydata.json` that I'd like to access in a couple places (specifically, in one of my models, as well as a module).

If this were a normal python script, obviously I'd do something like:

```
import json
with open('/path/to/mydata.json') as f:
    mydata = json.load(f)
```

In the context of web2py, I can get the url of the file from `URL('static', 'mydata.json')`, but I'm not sure how to load `mydata` - can I just do `mydata = json.load(URL('static','mydata.json')`? Or is there another step required to open the file?

Comment: Or is it just ``mydata = json.load(open('static/mydata.json'))``? If so, do I have to close the stream in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's advisable to use [os.path.join](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/02/the-python-language?search=os.path.join#os) with [request.folder](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core?search=request.folder) to build paths to files.

```
import os
filepath = os.path.join(request.folder,'static','mydata.json')
```

From that point on, you should be able to use that filepath to open the json file as per usual.

Answer (score 0):

import os
filepath = os.path.join(request.folder,'static','mydata.json')

mydata = json.load(filepath)